# Get only future records

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have the following query:

```
SELECT master.master_id, master.showname, 
MIN(CONCAT(shows.show_date, ' ', shows.show_time)) AS first_show_date, 
MAX(CONCAT(shows.show_date, ' ', shows.show_time)) AS last_show_date, master.showinfo
       FROM master LEFT OUTER JOIN
       shows ON master.master_id = shows.master_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       realtimeticketing rtt ON master.realtimeticketing_id = rtt.realtimeticketing_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       event_types ON master.event_type = event_types.event_types_id
       WHERE   (master.domainlist LIKE '%INTERNET%') 
       GROUP BY shows.master_id
       ORDER BY first_show_date, master.showname LIMIT 100;
```

This query returns the following output:

[image]

The requirement is that `master_id` 281 should be displayed as the first record since show dates lie within current date. And after 6th April 2014, the id 282 should start showing up.

I have tried various `WHERE` clauses but if I use `WHERE shows.show_date >= Now()`, it starts showing show dates from current date. I however require the `first_show_date` i.e. 01-03-2014 for `master_id` 281

Comment: Try to make a [sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want your current date to be before or on last show date. If that is the case try following `HAVING` clause.

```
HAVING MAX(CAST(CONCAT(shows.show_date, ' ', shows.show_time) AS DATETIME) >= Now()
```

Comment: Should be a `HAVING` clause, not `WHERE`

Comment: Agreed. This is a `GROUP BY` query and the condition is for an aggregate field. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

No experience from MySQL, but in other systems the next idea works

```
WHERE shows.show_date >=DATEADD(NOW(),1)
```

it should compare show_date to now + 1 day (see [Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) page) 
If you want just compare dates use ( if you are interested shows tomorrow not shows 24 hours later)

```
WHERE DATE(shows.show_date) >= DATEADD(DATE(NOW()),1)
```